# Getting active relationships using the API is returning contacts in trash

Tags: api

I'm doing this call

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Relationship', 'getvalue', [
  'return' => "contact_id_b",
  'relationship_type_id' => 5,
  'contact_id_a' => "user_contact_id",
  'is_active' => 1,
]);
```

It is returning contact B from contacts that are in trash.

I want to filter for contacts that are not in trash but struggling to find a way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work, using a join:

`$result = civicrm_api3('Relationship', 'get', [
      'sequential' => 1,
      'return' => ["contact_id_b"],
      'relationship_type_id' => 5,
      'contact_id_a' => "user_contact_id",
      'is_active' => 1,
      'contact_id_b.is_deleted' => 0,
    ]);`